# payload.getJSON is not a function when sending embed through webhook

Tags: discord, discord.js

Trying to make a basic webhook to send an embed. Sending a regular string of text works fine but trying to send the following embed:

```js
hook.send({
  embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${interaction.user.username} used ${interaction.commandName}`)
    .addFields(
      { name: "User ID", value: interaction.user.id, inline: true },
      { name: "Guild ID", value: `${interaction.guild ? interaction.guild.name : "DM"}`, inline: true },
    )
    .setColor("BLACK")
  ]
});
```

results in the following error:

```
[ERROR] Unhandled promise rejection: payload.getJSON is not a function.
TypeError: payload.getJSON is not a function
    at Webhook.send (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\bot\node_modules\discord-webhook-node\src\classes\webhook.js:56:28)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\bot\Events\Interaction Create\interactionCreate.js:116:20)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: Could you paste the full error in your question?

Comment: @Zsolt I added the full error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that is the correct code that is causing an issue for you, I have just written the code in a basic discord bot and it works.

[image: Discord Embed showing command working fine.]

```js
const { Client, Intents, WebhookClient, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

const hook = new WebhookClient({ url: 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/ID/TOKEN' })

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
        hook.send({
            embeds: [new MessageEmbed()
                .setDescription(`${interaction.user.username} used ${interaction.commandName}`)
                .addFields(
                    { name: "User ID", value: interaction.user.id, inline: true },
                    { name: "Guild ID", value: `${interaction.guild ? interaction.guild.name : "DM"}`, inline: true },
                )
                .setColor("BLACK")
            ]
        });
    }
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

This is the code that I used to get it working, if you give your code another look at as I do not think the problem is this code.

Comment: I was using a separate npm package to handle webhooks and I'm guessing that was the root of the problem because after setting up the webhook like yours, it worked fine.